# How to get intervals automatically without having to manually input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a react project:

I'm trying to get conversation history from specific date ranges. But let's say someone else wants to look for another date. How would I create a function that'll update the interval for the person is trying to search for.

```
  const getJobId = async () => {
let body = {
  interval: "2021-10-18T04:00:00.000Z/2021-10-31T04:00:00.000Z",
  order: "asc",
  orderBy: "conversationStart",
  paging: {
    pageSize: 4,
    pageNumber: 1,
  },
}; // Object | query

return (await apiInstance.postAnalyticsConversationsDetailsJobs(body))
  .jobId;
```

};

Comment: I am not exactly getting what you mean. This is what you are looking for?
const getJobId = async (interval) => {
const body = { interval, order: "asc", orderBy: "conversationStart", paging: { pageSize: 4, pageNumber: 1 }, };
return (await apiInstance.postAnalyticsConversationsDetailsJobs(body)).jobId;

Comment: I'm very horrible when it comes to explaining stuff. 

let say if a person chooses one date on the UI; I want the json data to automatically update. Like a startDate and an endDate if that make more sense?

Comment: let intervalRange = `${startDate}/${endDate}`

  const getJobId = async () => {
    let body = {
      interval: intervalRange,
      order: "asc",
      orderBy: "conversationStart",
      paging: {
        pageSize: 4,
        pageNumber: 1,
      },
    }; // Object | query


Something like this?

Comment: The desired date format is called ISO string. You should capture the user input for the beginning and the end and convert them with this function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString
so you can use new Date(date).toISOString() for both.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you

Comment: Could you upvote my comment please if you found it useful? Thank you in advance!